# How to set values in Struct object when does not know that type in iOS Swift 3.1?

Tags: swift, parsing, struct, properties

I made Struct object like this:

```
struct Lamp {
    var name:String!
    var age:Int!
}
```

And i have info Dictionary like this:

```
let infoDict = [
            "name":"Jason",
            "age":23
            ] as [String : Any]
```

And make new instance of Lamp struct object:

```
var lamp = Lamp()
```

And:

```
var labelsArr : Array<String>  = []
for property in Mirror(reflecting: lamp).children {
    print("label : \(String(describing:  property.label ))") //name , age
    labelsArr.append(property.label!)
}
```

So finally i want to set values of infoDict to lamp instance. **consider i do not want to set it manually like this:**

```
lamp.name = infoDict["name"]
lamp.age = infoDict["age"]
```

I want set these values **dynamically**. Because i do not know what properties have set in Lamp struct, the code must recognize what properties has been set in Lamp and set values by self.

Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should checkout [Unbox by John Sundell](https://github.com/JohnSundell/Unbox)

It's a really nice JSON decoder written in Swift.

Comment: it's best suggestion

Answer (score 2):

So I assume you don't know the type of `lamp` at compile time (so the compile time type is `Any`) and its type can only be in a finite set of types. And you want to initialise this lamp using JSON.

Now I am confused. Let's say you initialised `lamp` successfully, then what? Since you don't know what type it is, you can't really access any properties or methods.

Nevertheless, I thought of a solution. Make all the types that `lamp` can possibly be of conform to a protocol:

```
protocol JSONInitializable {
    func initialize(with json: [String: Any])
}
```

For example, the `Lamp` struct:

```
struct Lamp {
    ...

    func initialize(with json: [String: Any]) {
        name = json["name"] as! String
        age = json["age"] as! Int
    }
}
```

You do this for all other types.

When you want to initialise an unknown type `lamp`. You simply cast it to `JSONInitializable`:

```
if let jsonInitializable = lamp as? JSONInitializable {
    jsonInitializable.initialize(with: infoDict)
}
```